# Using WPF custom controls in Windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I made some custom controls in Expression Blend 4 using WPF. However, I need to use them in a Windows Forms application. Is this possible or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:[Hosting WPF Content in a Microsoft Win32 Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx)
See also:  [How do I host a WPF control in a Windows Forms application?](http://windowsclient.net/learn/integration.aspx)