# Exporting custom WPF buttons from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio, expression-blend

On my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472135/using-wpf-custom-controls-in-windows-forms) i asked how to use WPF controls in a Windows Form application. My answer was to go to [this website](http://windowsclient.net/learn/integration.aspx) and i clicked on the sixth option there. But heres my problem: the controlls are in a WPF application in Expression Blend 4, I need a way to put the controls as a resource or whatever onto my Winforms project ( I think i need to convert them into a WPF control library ) . How would I convert the buttons so I can add them to my form, and how would I add them there?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not mixing these technologies.  You have major interop issues between the two with focus, data binding, etc.  Your best option is to start replacing a form at a time in your win forms app with a WPF equivalent so you can migrate it to WPF over time.

Comment: is there any way to make controls like WPF controls in winforms? or do I have to start working towards WPF?

Comment: Not really.  Consider WPF the new way and a stepping stone to the next generation of MS development for the desktop.  WinForms will be supported but is not the recommended path.  Your best option is to cut your losses now and move in the right direction.